# How can you select and modify n-columns and select all remaining columns dynamically in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select some columns in MySQL and modify their values (not permanently) but i want to select the remaining columns of the table, too.

Is there some kind wildcard to do something like (just an imaginary example):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(a), CHAR_LENGTH(b), UPPER(c), <wildcard for remaining colums here> FROM `mysql_table`;
```

I want to do this on many different tables, so i don't want to hard code all column names for all tables in all mysql queries.

How can you achieve this?

Comment: That would lead me to duplicate columns which is very bad for my case.

Comment: If column name is duplicated,only one will be returned in results. The last one.

Comment: Oh i didn't knew that, so "SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(a) as a, ..." is the way to go?

Comment: Just tried on MySQL Server 5.6, doesn't work, leads to duplicate columns.

Comment: It seems that this happens on PHP side. My mistake. If you use PHP, it will work. Otherwise you probably have to make similar solution in language that you use.

Comment: You shouldn't really ever have code that does `SELECT *` or the variant you're looking for, because you are putting your application's performance at a potential disadvantage in the interest (presumably) of less typing. Better always select only what you need, allowing the server to potentially reduce the.amount of disk I/O and network bandwidth neeed for finding and delivering the result.  Yes, the difference can be more significant than you suspect.

Comment: That's correct, but as i said i want to do this on _many_ different tables (further on many different databases)..so doing it manually for each table is impossible.